# iOS modal views in stack dissmiss

Tags: ios, view, stack, modal-dialog

i have the following problem:

I have a storyboard containing three views with UIViewController classes. I do not use seques and apart from initial view (call it View A), all other views are created programmatically with presentViewController method. The problem i have is that when A opens B with presentViewController and then B opens C with presentViewController, when i dissmiss C with dismissViewControllerAnimated (in C there is a Button with Outlet to C UIViewController calling dismissViewControllerAnimated on self), C View disapears, and B appers but only for a 0.1 sec, and then i get C View showing again, and after that the close button wont work anymore.

Any idea what the reason might be?

Best Regards Edin

---

```
//delegate definition used between controller A/B and B/C
@protocol ParentControllerDelegate <NSObject>

//called as delegate method from B on A and from C on B to dismiss B from A and C from B
- (void)dismissView:(UIViewController*)controller;

@end


// MainMenuViewController.h which is controller A
@interface MainMenuViewController : UIViewController <ParentControllerDelegate>

//Controller B property
@property (strong, nonatomic) ChooseLevelViewController *chooseLevelViewController;
//button to open controller B
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *chooseLevelBtn;

@end

//MainMenuViewController.m - Controller A
@implementation MainMenuViewController

//called to present chooseLevelViewController which is controller B
- (IBAction)chooseLevelPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(self.chooseLevelViewController == nil)
    {
        self.chooseLevelViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseLevelView"];
        self.chooseLevelViewController.parentControllerDelegate = self;
    }
    [self presentViewController:self.chooseLevelViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//called from controller B over delegate mechanism to dismiss B
- (void)dismissView
{
    [self.chooseLevelViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end

// ChooseLevelViewController.h which is controller B
@interface ChooseLevelViewController : UIViewController <ParentControllerDelegate>

//Controller A as delegate
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <ParentControllerDelegate> parentControllerDelegate;
//Controller C property
@property (strong, nonatomic) ChoosePlayerViewController *choosePlayerViewController;
//button to dismiss B over delegate A
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backMainBtn;
//button to open C
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *choosePlayerBtn;

@end

//MainMenuViewController.m - controller B
@implementation ChooseLevelViewController

//calling controller A as delegate to dismiss B
- (IBAction)backMainBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.parentControllerDelegate dismissView];
}

//presenting choosePlayerViewController which is controller C
- (IBAction)choosePlayerBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(self.choosePlayerViewController == nil)
    {
        self.choosePlayerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChoosePlayerView"];
        self.choosePlayerViewController.parentControllerDelegate = self;
    }
    [self presentViewController:self.choosePlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


//called from controller C over delegate mechanism to dismiss C
- (void)dismissView:(UIViewController*)controller
{
    [self.choosePlayerViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end

//ChoosePlayerViewController.h which is controller C
@interface ChoosePlayerViewController : UIViewController

//Controller B as delegate
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <ParentControllerDelegate> parentControllerDelegate;
//button to dismiss C over delegate B
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *closeBtn;

@end

@implementation ChoosePlayerViewController

//calling controller B as delegate to dismiss C
- (IBAction)closeBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.parentControllerDelegate dismissView];
}
@end
```

Comment: Any ideas what the problem could be (plz see comments in first answer)?

Comment: Can you upload a sample project so that I can test this out?

Comment: okay ill do it in next few days, thnx

Answer (score 2):

You should NEVER have a view dismissing itself. You should always have the parent view dismiss the child.

- B should dismiss C
- A should dismiss B

Check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14
for more information.

[image]

Comment: Hi, i changed the source so, that the parent UIViewController implements delegate, which contains a method dissmiss. So if the user clicks a close button on child view it calls the delegate method of parent, which contains `[self.childControler dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` But the problem still remains: for the modal B view with parent A, it works well, but for the modal C with parent B   after dismissing C, B is shown for a 0.1 sec and then i see C again and the close button do have no affect anymore. For B and C i implemented same delegate behaviour as with A and B.

Comment: Check your `viewWillAppear` on B and make sure it isn't calling C. Also check your `viewWillUnload` on C and make sure it isn't calling something else.

Comment: I do not implement those methods. I am asking myself why it works from A (which is initial View in storyboard) to B without problems. I also dont want to switch from C to A (which is often discussed here), on B user have two buttons  so he can decide either to go back to A (calling delegate implemented by A to `self.B dismissViewControllerAnimated` or open C again (implemented in B with `self presentViewController:self.C`. C itselfs calls on close Button its delegate B that implements `self.C dismissViewControllerAnimated`. That error switch to C occurs somehow without animation.

Comment: my question is why are you not using `pushViewController` with a navigation controller? we will need to see your code to further help you.

Comment: i do not use navigation controller. i have a little game that was created with ios 4. the menu area of the game is made with UIKit and was first created with buch of nib files. The play area is made with sparrow framework for ios games. i dont want to redesign whole menu area and put all that views into navigation controller (at least at moment), only to eliminate all that nib files with one storyboard. I will put simplified version of that three controllers as a new answer for my question in a moment